# increasing sequences.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Consider the sequence $\langle b_n\rangle$, where $b_n$ is given by 
$$b_n=\left \{\begin{array}{lr} 2\cot\frac {\pi}{n}, &\mbox{if $n\equiv 0\pmod 4$},\\
2\csc\frac {\pi}{n}, &\mbox{if $n\equiv 2\pmod 4$},\\
\csc\frac {\pi}{2n}, ~~~~&\mbox{if $n\equiv 1\pmod 2$}.\\
\end{array} \right. $$
I know that $\langle b_n\rangle$ is strictly increasing for $n\ge 4$. That is 
$$2\cot\frac {\pi}{4k}<\csc\frac {\pi}{2(4k+1)}<2\csc\frac {\pi}{4k+2}<\csc\frac {\pi}{2(4k+3)}<2\cot\frac {\pi}{4(k+1)}.$$ holds for $k\ge 1$.
A computer calculation shows that if $r$ is a positive real number then $\langle r^{\frac{1}{n}} b_n\rangle$, $n\ge 4$ is also strictly increasing. For $0<r\le 1$ it is true because $\langle r^{\frac{1}{n}}\rangle$ and $\langle b_n\rangle$ both increase. But for $r>1$ the sequence $\langle r^{\frac1n}\rangle$ decreases and $\langle b_n\rangle$ increases. Please help me how we can prove it.
In earlier post some text is missing so I am posting once again.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! In this case, you should edit the original post, instead of posting one question twice.

Comment: I have deleted the earlier incomplete post, so no harm done. But please keep in mind that you can always edit your posts to add things you have forgotten. In future, be aware that editing the question rather than posting a new version is the right course of action.

Comment: Let $r=10^{20}$. Then you are saying, $10^5(2\cot(\pi/4)<10^4\csc(\pi/10)$. Is that true?

Comment: Dear Sir Thank you very much for correcting me.